# Why does the putting text did this?

Tags: python, text, pygame

I want to make simple platformer game. everything goes OK, but when I tried to put text in here something weird happened. I really don´t know why this happened, because I did the same as in my previous projects
here is printscreen:
[image]

If you know why this happened and why is this still happening, please tell me
and here´s my code:

````
from pygame import *
WIN_WIDTH = 1923
WIN_HEIGHT = 1000
DISPLAY = (WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT)
DEPTH = 32
FLAGS = 0
CAMERA_SLACK = 30
pygame.init()
green = (0, 255, 0)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(DISPLAY, FLAGS, DEPTH)
level = [
'PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP',
'P                                                          P',
'P                                                          P',
'P                        PP                                P',
'P                                                          P',
'P                                 PP                       P',
'P                                                          P',
'P                                                          P',
'P             PP                                           P',
'P                                                          P',
'P                                                          P',
'P                                                          P',
'P                                                          P',
'P                     PP                                   P',
'P                                                          P',
'P                                                          P',
'P                                                          P',
'P                                                   P      P',
'P                            PP                     P      P',
'P                                                   P      P',
'P                                                   P      P',
'P                                                   P      P',
'P                    PP                             P      P',
'P                                                   P      P',
'P                                                   P      P',
'P           PP                                      P      P',
'P                                                   P      P',
'P                      PPP                          P     PP',
'P                                                   P      P',
'P                                                   P     LP',
    'PSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSPPPSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSPSSPPPPPPP',
]
def main():
    pygame.display.set_caption('BlaBlabla!')
    timer = pygame.time.Clock()
    up = down = left = right = running = left_dash = right_dash = dashing = False
    bg = Surface((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT  // 30))
    bg.convert()
    bg.fill(Color('#000000'))
    text = 'Score:'
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('Consolas', 22)
    bg.blit(font.render(text, True, (green)), (1, 1))
    entities = pygame.sprite.Group()
    platforms = []
    killing_entities = []
    another_level = []
    blockade = []
    player = Player(767, 900)
    x = y = 0
    global level
    for row in level:
        for col in row:
            if col == 'P':
                p = Platform(x, y)
                platforms.append(p)
                entities.add(p)
            if col == 'E':
                e = Block(x, y)
                platforms.append(e)
                entities.add(e)
            if col == 'S':
                s = Spike(x, y)
                killing_entities.append(s)
                entities.add(s)
            if col == 'L':
                l = Another_Level(x, y)
                another_level.append(l)
                entities.add(l)
            x += 32
        y += 32
        x = 0
    entities.add(player)
    run = True
    while run:
        timer.tick(65)
        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == QUIT:
                run = False
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_SPACE:
                up = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_s:
                down = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_a:
                left = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_d:
                right = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_q:
                running = True              
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_SPACE:
                up = False
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_s:
                down = False
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_d:
                right = False
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_a:
                left = False
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_d:
                right = False
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(player, killing_entities):
            main()
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(player, another_level):
            level = [
'PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP',
'P             S           S            S             S     P',
'P                   S           S             S            P',
'P         PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP  P',
'PP        P   P   P     SS      SS         S     S         P',
'PS        P P S P S     SS  SS  SS  SS     S  S  S  S      P',
'P         P S P S P     SS  SS  SS  SS     S  S  S  S      P',
'P         P P   P     S     SS      SS        S     S      P',
'P         P PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPSSP',
'PP                                                       EEP',
'PS                                                         P',
'P                                                          P',
'P                                                          P',
'P                                                          P',
'PP                                                         P',
'PS                                                         P',
'P                                                          P',
'P                                                          P',
'P                                                          P',
'PPS                                                        P',
'PS                                                         P',
'P                                                          P',
'P                                                          P',
'P                                                          P',
'PP                                                         P',
'P                                                          P',
'P                                                          P',
'P                                                          P',
'P                                                          P',
'P         P                                                P',
    'PSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSPPPSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSPPPP',]
            main()
        for y in range(32):
            for x in range(32):
                screen.blit(bg, (x * 32, y * 32))
        player.update(up, down, left, right, left_dash, right_dash, running, dashing, platforms)
        entities.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.display.update()
class Entity(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
class Player(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.xvel = 0
        self.yvel = 0
        self.onGround = False
        self.image = Surface((32,32))
        self.image.fill(Color('#0000FF'))
        self.image.convert()
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 32)
    def update(self, up, down, left, right, running, platforms):
        if up:
            if self.onGround: self.yvel -= 9
        if down:
            pass
        if running:
            self.xvel = 12
        if left:
            self.xvel = -8
        if right:
            self.xvel = 8
        if not self.onGround:
            self.yvel += 0.25
            if self.yvel > 100: self.yvel = 100
        if not(left or right):
            self.xvel = 0        
        self.rect.left += self.xvel
        self.collide(self.xvel, 0, platforms)
        self.rect.top += self.yvel
        self.onGround = False
        self.collide(0, self.yvel, platforms)
    def collide(self, xvel, yvel, platforms):
        for p in platforms:
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, p):
                if isinstance(p, Block):
                    pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(QUIT))
                if xvel > 0:
                    self.rect.right = p.rect.left
                if xvel < 0:
                    self.rect.left = p.rect.right
                if yvel > 0:
                    self.rect.bottom = p.rect.top
                    self.onGround = True
                    self.yvel = 0
                if yvel < 0:
                    self.rect.top = p.rect.bottom
                    self.onGround = False
class Platform(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.image = Surface((32, 32))
        self.image.convert()
        self.image.fill(Color('#DDDDDF'))
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 32)
    def update(self):
        pass
class Spike(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Platform.__init__(self, x, y)
        self.image = Surface((32, 32))
        self.image.convert()
        self.image.fill(Color('#E70018'))
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 32)
class Another_Level(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Platform.__init__(self, x, y)
        self.image = Surface((32, 32))
        self.image.convert()
        self.image.fill(Color('#8C563E'))
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 32)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
pygame.quit()```
````

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You blit the text to the `bg` Surface. Then you blit that Surface to the screen 1024 times, every 32 pixel in each direction:

```
for y in range(32):
    for x in range(32):
        screen.blit(bg, (x * 32, y * 32))
```

Either make `bg` big enough to cover the entire screen and *blit it once*:

```
bg = Surface(DISPLAY)
bg.convert()
bg.fill(Color('#000000'))
text = 'Score:'
font = pygame.font.SysFont('Consolas', 22)
bg.blit(font.render(text, True, (green)), (100, 100))

...

# in the main loop
    screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
```

or store the text surface and blit that once per frame to the *screen* and not to `bg`:

```
bg = Surface((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT  // 30))
bg.convert()
bg.fill(Color('#000000'))
text = 'Score:'
font = pygame.font.SysFont('Consolas', 22)
text_surf, text_rect = font.render(text, True, (green)), (1, 1)
entities = pygame.sprite.Group()
...


# in the main loop:
    screen.fill('black')
    screen.blit(text_surf, (100, 100))
```

Comment: I tried the second option, but when I do this, there is no text.

Comment: You have to remove the `for y in range(32):    for x in range(32): ...` part.